# Edit any input field in emacs buffer

Tags: text-editing

Is it possible to make emacs as an input middle man for any text field in the system? It should work like this:

1 user focus the text input field of any gui program

2 a system hotkey brings up a dedicated emacs buffer

3 user do the editing in that emacs buffer

4 when finished editing, a short cut key send text to the original text input field

Possible problem is between step 3 and 4, the user may change windows.

Possible reference is the input method program fcitx, which has a pre-edit window, the editing is done in a separated popup window, a key need to be pressed to commit the content. What we need is to change the pre-edit window to an emacs buffer.

issue on fcitx tracker (https://github.com/fcitx/fcitx/issues/232)

Comment: probably depends on "the system", e.g. you can use [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) for Firefox.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a way to generalize that to all applications.